# Per-machine include/library paths (for JNI projects) in VS 2022, now that user props are deprecated

Tags: visual-studio, java-native-interface, visual-studio-2022

Question: How do I replace the deprecated .user.props files to set per-machine include, library, and executable paths? Alternatively: How do I work around the problem that requires these settings, which is depending on the JDK for a JNI project?

Background: I have a Visual C++ project that builds the native side of a Java library. This requires adjustments to the include path (so that the JNI headers are found), and for testing it also requires per-architecture adjustments to the executable path. That is to say, for an x64 configuration it needs to point to the 64-bit JDK, for a Win32 configuration it to the 32-bit JDK.

To provide the JDK, I'm using Eclipse Temurin (formerly Adoption, formerly AdoptJDK). This means the JDK ends up in a path like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-11.0.20.101-hotspot`, which changes with every patch level release.

This means a few things:

1. it's not practical to have the path tied to the git repository because the path is (in general) different on different machines
2. I can't rely on environment variables because the executable path needs to be different per project configuration

So far I've been solving this problem with `Microsoft.Cpp.*.user.props` files. This still works, but they have been declared deprecated by Microsoft (see https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/how-to-set-up-global-include-path-for-c/518994). Their workaround is to use per-project props files, which does not solve this issue.

As I understand it, Microsoft's view on the issue is that per-user, per-machine settings are bad because they can introduce subtle problems where the build behavior changes depending on the building machine (imagine someone overriding the default C++ standard version, manifest settings or something of the sort in a .user.props and then having to debug the issue). I understand where they're coming from, but when the paths are only valid on a per-machine basis, it seems like the only reasonable option to set them on a per-machine basis. So how do I do that, or what do I do instead?